# Mapping entity oneToMany with fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

The problem appears to be simple however I'm having so much trouble trying to map this entities. I just can't see what am I doing wrong. Can you guys help me?

I have the class `Cliente`:

```
public class Cliente
{    
    public Cliente () { }
    public virtual int ClienteId { get; set; }  
    public IList<Medidor> ListaMedidores { get; set; }   
    public virtual string NumeroMedidor { get; set; }       
}
```

And class `Medidor`

```
public class Medidor
{
    public Medidor() { }
    public virtual string NumeroMedidor { get; set; }
    public virtual string MarcaMedidor { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to map like this

```
public ClienteMap()
{
    Map(x => x.NumeroMedidor).Column("CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR");
    HasMany(x => x.ListaMedidores)
        .KeyColumn("NUMERO_MEDIDOR").Inverse().Cascade.All();
}


public MedidorMap()
{
    Table("medidor");
    LazyLoad();

    Id(x => x.NumeroMedidor).Column("NUMERO_MEDIDOR");
    Map(x => x.TipoMedidor).Column("TIPO_MEDIDOR");
    References(x => x.Cliente).Column("CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR");
}
```

The goal is bring my List of `Medidor` according to database.
So I did:

```
Session.Query<Cliente>().Fetch(x => x.ListaMedidores).ToList();
```

And i'm getting the list always empty. Even having data on those tables... I would appreciate any kind of help or suggestion.

Regards

EDIT

My database is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(
  CORE_ID                      NUMBER           NOT NULL,
  CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR          VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
)

CREATE TABLE MEDIDOR
(
  NUMERO_MEDIDOR  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  MARCA_MEDIDOR   VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
)
```

Given the sql `select * from cliente where core_numero_medidor = '3569371'`:

```
CORE_ID CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR
123     3569371
```

and the sql `select * from MEDIDOR where numero_medidor = '3569371'`:

```
NUMERO_MEDIDOR MARCA_MEDIDOR
3569371        general_motors
3569371        kia
3569371        FIAT
```

So I'm suppose to get 3 elements on my `IList<Medidor> Lista Medidores` on `Cliente` class..

**EDIT**

I changed to this:

```
public class Cliente
{    
    public Cliente () { }
    public virtual int ClienteId { get; set; }  
    public IList<Medidor> ListaMedidores { get; set; }   
    public virtual string NumeroMedidor { get; set; }       
}
public class Medidor
{
    public Medidor() { }
    public virtual string NumeroMedidor { get; set; }
    public virtual string MarcaMedidor { get; set; }
}
```

And changed the map of `ClienteMap` to:

```
Map(x => x.NumeroMedidor).Column("NUMERO_MEDIDOR");    
HasMany(x => x.ListaMedid)
            .KeyColumns.Add("NUMERO_MEDIDOR")
            .Table("MEDID")
            .PropertyRef("CoreNumeroCliente")
            .Cascade.All();
```

and now the list gets the expected number of records but all of them its the same as the first one. ie:

**Expected**

```
NUMERO_MEDIDOR MARCA_MEDIDOR
3569371        general_motors
3569371        kia
3569371        FIAT
```

**My result**

```
NUMERO_MEDIDOR MARCA_MEDIDOR
3569371        general_motors
3569371        general_motors
3569371        general_motors
```

Any suggestions? I would like to thank @Radim Köhler so far for the help.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I found the solution!

I was trying to map a non-unique column as a primary key... I just changed the column to a real primary key and worked!

So now here's the solution

```
public class Cliente
{    
    public Cliente () { }
    public virtual int ClienteId { get; set; }  
    public IList<Medidor> ListaMedidores { get; set; }   
    public virtual string NumeroMedidor { get; set; }       
}
public class Medidor
{
    public Medidor() { }
    public virtual string NumeroMedidor { get; set; }
    public virtual string MarcaMedidor { get; set; }
}

public class ClienteMap : ClassMap<Cliente>
{
    public ClienteMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.NumeroMedidor).Column("NUMERO_MEDIDOR");    
        HasMany(x => x.ListaMedid)
            .KeyColumns.Add("NUMERO_MEDIDOR")
            .Table("MEDID")
            .PropertyRef("CoreNumeroCliente")
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class MedidorMap : ClassMap<Medidor>
{
    public MedidorMap()
    {
        LazyLoad();

        Id(x => x.NumeroMedidor).Column("NUMERO_MEDIDOR");
        Map(x => x.MarcaMedidor).Column("MARCA_MEDIDOR");
        [...] //Other properties
    }
}
```

And here is my query:

```
Session.Query<CorteReligacao>()
                .Fetch(x => x.ListaMedid)
```

I really would like to thanks Radim Köhler for the help. His patience, attention and willingness to helping solve the problem leaves me with lack of way of thanks..I can only wish him all the best in life.

And I really hope that this thread may help people with the same problem.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, with these SQL scripts *(adjust for SQL Server in my case)*

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(
  CORE_ID                      int           NOT NULL,
  CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR          VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE MEDIDOR
(
  NUMERO_MEDIDOR  VARCHAR(50),
  MARCA_MEDIDOR   VARCHAR(50)
)
```

With these entities *(all properties are virtual)*

```
public class Cliente
{    
    public virtual int ClienteId { get; set; }  
    public virtual IList<Medidor> ListaMedidores { get; set; }   
    public virtual string NumeroMedidor { get; set; }       
}
public class Medidor
{
    public virtual string NumeroMedidor { get; set; }
    public virtual string MarcaMedidor { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

and with **only this one** mapping in place:

```
public class ClienteMap: ClassMap<Cliente>
{
    public ClienteMap()
    {
        Table("CLIENTE");
        Id(x => x.ClienteId, "CORE_ID");
        Map(x => x.NumeroMedidor).Column("CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR");
        HasMany(x => x.ListaMedidores)
            .KeyColumn("NUMERO_MEDIDOR")
            .Component(com =>
            {
                com.ParentReference(y => y.Cliente);
                com.Map(y => y.MarcaMedidor, "MARCA_MEDIDOR");
            })
            .PropertyRef("NumeroMedidor")
            .Table("MEDIDOR")
            // .Inverse() // NO INVERSE, won't work
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

I can confirm, that this query will work:

```
var list = session.Query<Cliente>().Fetch(x => x.ListaMedidores).ToList();
var firt = list.First().ListaMedidores.First();
var last = list.First().ListaMedidores.Last();
Assert.IsTrue(firt.MarcaMedidor != last.MarcaMedidor);
```

BTW, this will be ***(my preferred)*** generated `xml` mapping:

```
<class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="Cliente" table="CLIENTE">
    <id name="ClienteId" type="System.Int32">
      <column name="CORE_ID" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <bag cascade="all" name="ListaMedidores" table="MEDIDOR">
      <key property-ref="NumeroMedidor">
        <column name="NUMERO_MEDIDOR" />
      </key>
      <composite-element class="Medidor">
        <parent name="Cliente" />
        <property name="MarcaMedidor" type="System.String">
          <column name="MARCA_MEDIDOR" />
        </property>
      </composite-element>
    </bag>
    <property name="NumeroMedidor" type="System.String">
      <column name="CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR" />
    </property>
</class>
```

For documentation see:

[7.2. Collections of dependent objects](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#components-incollections)

Comment: you're the guy! ahaha I just updated the question with solution thanks to you. I just had to remove the .Component mapping because I have other properties on `Medidor` class. I wish all the best for you man.. thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

The `one-to-many` and `many-to-one` are always related by one column. This is such column, which contains reference ID (foreign key) to the other table / entity.

In our case, it must be column in table of **`Medidor`**, and its name would be **`"CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR"`**. The mapping should look like this

```
public ClienteMap()
{
    ...
    HasMany(x => x.ListaMedidores)
       //.KeyColumn("NUMERO_MEDIDOR")
       .KeyColumn("CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR") // column in other table
       .Inverse().Cascade.All();
}


public MedidorMap()
{
    ...
    References(x => x.Cliente)
        .Column("CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR");  // column in this table
}
```

#### EXTEND

Based on extended question, when we can see this structure of tables

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(
  CORE_ID                      NUMBER           NOT NULL,
  CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR          VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
)

CREATE TABLE MEDIDOR
(
  NUMERO_MEDIDOR  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  MARCA_MEDIDOR   VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
)
```

That the DB reference is different then in C#. It seems, like if

> table CLIENTE references just **one** MEDIDOR, while MEDIDOR has many CLIENTEs.

It seems that the objects should look like this:

```
public class Cliente
{    
    ...
    //public IList<Medidor> ListaMedidores { get; set; }    
    //public Medidor Medidor { get; set; }    
}

public class Medidor
{
    ...
    //public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
}
```

and the mapping should be

```
public ClienteMap()
{
    ...
    References(x => x.Medidor, "CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR");
}


public MedidorMap()
{
    ...
    Id(x => x.NumeroMedidor).Column("NUMERO_MEDIDOR")
                               // column in this table to be compared
    HasMany(x => x.Clientes)
       .KeyColumn("CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR") // with column in other table
       .Inverse().Cascade.All();
}
```

#### ANOTHER EXTEND

Because the second table MEDIDOR is not having its own primary key (column NUMERO_MEDIDOR) but it could contain many same values... coming from CLIENT TABLE... we should use component mapping

```
public ClienteMap()
{
    ...
    Map(x => x.NumeroMedidor).Column("CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR");
    HasMany(x => x.ListaMedidores)
        .Component(com =>
        {
            com.Parent(y => y.Cliente, "NUMERO_MEDIDOR")
               .PropertyRef("NumeroMedidor")
               ;
            com.Map(y => y.MarcaMedidor, "MARCA_MEDIDOR");
        })
        .PropertyRef("NumeroMedidor")
        .Table("MEDIDOR")
       // .Inverse() // NO INVERSE, won't work
       .Cascade.All();

}
```

Comment: Sorry.. I tryed this already... then I got this as inner exception

"ORA-00904: \"LISTAMEDIDORES3_\".\"CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR\": invalid identifier"

Maybe something wrong with database? I have no foreign key on table `Medidor`... neither pk..

Comment: Could you extend your answer with full exception? Anyhow, my mapping is the way to go. We have to use same column on both sides... also, could you please confirm, that the REFERENCE column is "CORE_NUMERO_MEDIDOR"? I am still not sure about your table structure, so maybe .. .could you show (simplified) create script?

Comment: Great, will check that

Comment: Thanks man. This would be simple solved with a left outer join on SQL... I will edit the question with some select data on each tables.

Comment: I would say, that my answer (extended part) is now correct, but it means lot of changes to your model

Comment: @Köhler, on my scenario, I can have more than one `Cliente` with the same `Medidor`. I have edited the question with some select that might help. I just checked your answer with extended part. In that way, I wont be able to retrieve a List of `Cliente` with each client having a full list of their `Medidor` right?

Comment: OK, this means totally different world. These tables are not joined by the primary key. That's the first issue. And the second table (MEDIDOR) is not in fact an entity, it does not have its ID. It should be mapped as a component...

Comment: I think I understand... If I get the `Cliente` "Medidor", I can access "Medidor" properties and get the List, right? Thanks mate! That `Medidor` table is kinda of filled on an external way... a webservice should do that... so it's not necessary to have a primary key, right? I will check your changes and I will come back with feedback asap. Thanks mate!

Comment: I drafted another solution, with component mapping... hope it help

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work...now i'm getting `property not found: JobTypeAndCode on entity Cliente`... and I can't use the .Parent map.

I'm using HasMany(x => x.ListaMedidores)
            .Component(com =>
                           {
                               com.ParentReference(y => y.Cliente);
                               com.Map(y => y.NumeroMedidor, "NUMERO_MEDIDOR");
                           })
            .PropertyRef("JobTypeAndCode")
            .Table("MEDIDOR")
            .Cascade.All();

Comment: Sorry... that is type... sorry... I updated the answer. It should be **`.PropertyRef("NumeroMedidor")`** (just copy past from my stuff ;)... This setting is saying - map that table (medidor) with my table ... but not by ID, not by primary key... but by other property... in our case NumeroMedidor. Hope it is clear now ;)

Comment: Not working... but I think we are close... i'm getting this `{"ORA-00904: \"LISTAMEDIDORES3_\".\"CLIENTE_ID\": invalid identifier"}` And I am doing this: HasMany(x => x.ListaMedid).Component(com =>
                           {
                               com.ParentReference(y => y.CorteReligacao);
                               com.Map(y => y.NumeroCliente, "NUMERO_CLIENTE");
                           })
            .PropertyRef("CoreNumeroCliente")
            .Table("MEDID")
            .Cascade.All(); - I got the generated SQL and modified the `ClienteID` to "CoreNumeroOrdem" and worked

Comment: I cannot believe it... it seems that I again made a type with cliente.... I updated my answer with `com.Parent(y => y.Cliente, "NUMERO_MEDIDOR") .PropertyRef("NumeroMedidor")`... or something like this... we simply have to do the same with Parent mapping as we did with collection...Have to go... hope you have the direction and will make it ;)

Comment: We're almost there @Radim, I updated the question with the changes...can you take a loot please?